# Table caption exceeding page margins when using captionsetup and xltabular with cleveref active

Tags: captions, margins, longtable, cleveref, xltabular

today I discovered a strange side-effect which I would like to share in the community and gather your insights and feedback. As indicated below, there is a workaround for the issue by not using the package `cleveref` if working with `xltabular` and `captionsetup`. The negative side-effect occurs only for `xltabular` tables, not for `tabularx` or `tabular` ones.

**MWE showing the desired effect**

Note that in the following code, the package `cleveref` is commented out.

```
\documentclass[preprint, numbers]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{
   labelfont = bf,
   labelsep = newline,
   indention = 0cm,
   singlelinecheck = off,
   justification = raggedright,
   textformat = period
}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdfauthor={Name}, bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksdepth=3, breaklinks]{hyperref}
% \usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{Test section}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}lll@{}}
    \caption{Test caption}       
    \label{appendix:CodingScheme}
    \\ % This line break is needed, otherwise timeout in compilation
        \toprule
         Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 \\\midrule
         Field 1 & Field 2 & Field 3 \\
        \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Result: The table caption stays within page margins.
[image: Good example]

However, running the same code with `cleveref` active, the table caption **exceeds the page margins**.

[image]

Comment: you have no X column so should use longtable not xltabular, it seems better if you keep the label in the caption `\begin{longtable}{@{}lll@{}}
    \caption{Test caption\label{appendix:CodingScheme}}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mostly due to your lazy use of the `\label` command. While often it doesn't matter if you put it inside the argument or not, and if you add spaces before, it this case it does. cleveref internally adds another label and hyperref adds code too. Look at the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{
   labelfont = bf,
   labelsep = newline,
   indention = 0cm,
   singlelinecheck = off,
}

%\usepackage[]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\LTpre=\smallskipamount
\LTpost=\smallskipamount
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}lll@{}}
    \caption{Test caption} \label{appendix:CodingScheme0}
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{@{}lll@{}}
    \caption{Test caption} \label{appendix:CodingScheme1}\label{appendix:CodingScheme2}
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{@{}lll@{}}
    \caption{Test caption}\label{appendix:CodingScheme3}\label{appendix:CodingScheme4}
\end{longtable}


\begin{longtable}{@{}lll@{}}
    \caption{Test caption\label{appendix:CodingScheme6}\label{appendix:CodingScheme5}}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

### without hyperref and cleveref:

[image]

### with hyperref

[image]

### with hyperref and cleveref

[image]